# class A : IA, where IA inherits IB vs class A: IA, IB

Tags: inheritance, interface

What's the difference?

```
class A : IA (IA inherits IB)
```

vs

```
class A: IA, IB (IA and IB might have no relation)
```

IA and IB are interfaces.

One difference I know: you don't need to know whether IB exists in the 1st implementation.

Comment: why is *C#* tagged in this question?!

Comment: @akjha it's nice if you select an answer. Helps everyone if a question is marked answered. You got two decent answers to choose from :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no *difference*. Remember that you don't *have* to use either Interface.

It is a design choice. It depends on how you structure your **Interfaces**.

In your example it might not matter which way you did. `Fish:IAqautic, IEatAndSwim` forces you to implement behavior (functions) for both interfaces. Here, semantically at-least, `IAqautic, IEatAndSwim` seem to be similar. We would have to know how they are similar/different to judge the gain/loss of the different design choices.

Assuming that `IAqautic` and `IEatAndSwim` are functionally different, then the gain/loss would be in the case that some **Object** only wants one of the two. Then you can use the one that applies and not have to use the *extra* functions from the second **Interface**.

Assuming that `IAqautic` and `IEatAndSwim` are **functionally similar**, then the gain/loss would be in a case where you want both. If `IEatAndSwim` is a special case of `IAqautic` then you can have `IEatAndSwim` extend `IAqautic`. You only need to use one **Interface** and your code/intent is clearer.

In short, this question really depends on what is the relationship between the Interfaces. You would use he one that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have an interface

```
interface IEat
{
}
interface Swim
{
}
```

When creating a Fish you would say

```
class Fish:IEat,ISwim
{
}
```

Instead of above implementation you can create another interface:-

```
 interface IAquatic:IEat,ISwim{}
```

//Here you can define more behavior to make it aquatic which can later be used by your class.

```
class Fish:IAquatic
{
}

class AnotherAquaticAnimal:IAquatic
{
}
```

IEat,ISwim are all different set of behavior that can be associated with Human,Aquatic or another living being, if there are 10 such behaviors to make a aquatic animal you have to remember and implement all of them while creating any aquatic animal.

Instead what we do is we create and interface IAquatic and inherit all the interfaces to this interface, now all you have to remember is implementing this IAquatic interface instead of those 10 interfaces, this makes your life easy.

Comment: Vinay, I didn't understand your answer. Again my question is instead of doing class Fish:IAquatic, what is gained/lost by doing class Fish:IAqautic, IEatAndSwim where I would change IAquatic such that it doesn't extend IEatAndSwim

Comment: So, in your opinion, its just a convenience, than required for any special purpose. Instead of implementing 10 interfaces, I create a parent interface and implement that. I also thought that, that's why I stated in my question "One difference I know: you don't need to know whether IB exists in the 1st implementation." Thanks Vinay :)